# Equivalent of the build step for the Job DSL plugin?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

The Pipeline: Build Step plugin. i.e. here:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-build-step/
and https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

has `build`.

What would be the equivalent with the Job DSL Plugin?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. Job DSL plugin is used to define/configure jobs in a programmatic way. The `build` step is not part of a job configuration.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achieve. You may create a `pipelineJob` by using Job DSL and that job can execute the `build` step. What does it mean "equivalent with the Job DSL Plugin"? Job DSL provisions Jenkins configuration, it is not designed to execute other builds.